# Why python.exe stopped working?

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I try to use OpenCV for Python. I have just two lines of the code:

```
import cv
capture = cv.CreateFileCapture('test.avi')
```

If I run this code from the command line, Windows creates a window with the following message:

```
python.exe stopped working
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.
Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.
```

What can be the a reason of that?

---

I would like to add some details. Not sure if they are relevant. In the examples that I found people use `cvCreateFileCapture` instead of `cv.CreateFileCapture`. But in this case my program generate a NameError (cvCreateFileCapture is not found).

In general I was able to do a simple stuff with the OpenCV (so, it is installed and it works). For example I was able to change format of an image:

```
import cv
im = cv.LoadImageM("test.jpg")
print type(im)
cv.SaveImage("test.png", im)
```

**ADDED**

"In OpenCV2.2\samples\python" I found many *.py samples. I run some of them and they work fine (I see some animation and so on). The I tried to find a file that contains "CreateFileCapture". I found only one such file (minidemo.py) and I run it. As a result I got the same problem as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Python on opencv has changed, [see here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface) make sure you have the latest opencv install - you might also need numpy